# Cannot create an instance of a model with GenericForeignKey in migration

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-migrations

**IMPORTANT:** This question is no longer relevant.

---

In a Django 1.7 migration I try to create Comment entries programatically with the following code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models, migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def create_genericcomment_from_bookingcomment(apps, schema_editor):

        BookingComment = apps.get_model('booking', 'BookingComment')
        Comment = apps.get_model('django_comments', 'Comment')
        for comment in BookingComment.objects.all():
            new = Comment(content_object=comment.booking)
            new.save()

    dependencies = [
        ('comments', '0001_initial'),
        ('django_comments', '__first__'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_genericcomment_from_bookingcomment),
    ]
```

And it produces an error:
`TypeError: 'content_object' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

However, the same code (i.e. `Comment(content_object=comment.booking)`) works when executed in the shell.

I tried to create a blank model with `new = Comment()` and then set all the necessary fields manually but even though I set `content_type` and `object_pk` fields accordingly, they `content_type` was not actually saved and I received `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "content_type_id" violates not-null constraint`

Any idea how to properly create a model with a generic foreign key in a migration? Or any workaround?

Comment: Can you paste the models? At least the relevant bit? 
I'm running into the same situation trying to create a simple model that is the target of a M2M field. The model itself has no relation field.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue of migrations' model loader. You load your models using default

```
Comment = apps.get_model('django_comments', 'Comment')
```

It loads the `Comment` model in some special way, so some features like generic relations don't work.

There is a bit hacky solution: load your models as usual:

```
from django_comments import Comment
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't even a solution. It works until you add a field to Comment; at that point during migration the upto date model generates SQL for the schema version which is to be applied in a later migration. So any long term project which has older database hanging around can no longer apply ir migrations